# Бот не обрабатывает несколько запросов одновременно (aiogram 2+, webhook, nginx). Как это исправить? При использовании поллинга все работает

Tags: python, aiogram, nginx, aiohttp, webhook

Я задеплоил бота на сервер, предварительно настроив вебхук c помощью start_webhook (aiogram + aiohttp):

```
    if IS_WEBHOOK == 1:
    start_webhook(
        dispatcher=dp,
        webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH,
        on_startup=on_startup,
        on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
        skip_updates=True,
        host=WEBAPP_HOST,
        port=WEBAPP_PORT,
    )
```

Настроил reverse proxy nginx:

```
server {
server_name mydomainnname.com;

location / {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ontech.one/fullchain.pem; # managed b>
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ontech.one/privkey.pem; # managed>
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
location /mywebhookpath {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:2222;
}




server {
 if ($host = mydomainnname) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


listen 80;
server_name ontech.one;
return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Проблема, с которой я столкнулся, заключается в следующем:
Тело бота написано на aiogram, код при использовании метода polling работает асинхронно и обрабатывает множество запросов одновременно, но когда я запускаю бота на сервере и использую вебхук - бот теряет способность обрабатывать несколько процессов одновременно и начинает работать синхронно. В чем может быть причина подобного поведения? Пытался перенастроить nginx; ничего из этого не вышло.